# tshark not resolving hostnames

Tags: hostname, tshark

I'm trying to watch on-line to what external hosts one from my laptops (192.168.1.6) tries to access. It works - but no matter what - tshark is not resolving dest IP to hostname. Here is command I'm launching on my firewall/gateway (192.168.1.254):

```
tshark -N n -T fields -e ip.src_host -e tcp.srcport -e ip.dst_host -e tcp.dstport src 192.168.1.6 and dst not 192.168.1.254 and not broadcast and not multicast
```

What wrongly I'm doing here?

Comment: Have you tried leaving out the `-N n` or replacing it with `-N N` ?

Comment: Yes. Removing -N n or going with -N N not helps. still no hostnames....Interesting that running: tshark -G currentprefs | grep "resolve"   gives: #nameres.use_external_name_resolver: TRUE (note # at beginning). How can I change this setting?